# How can I convert an image to a web-safe color map in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors

I want to convert images to web-safe colors using MATLAB. Is there any predefined function for it? If not, what should be my first step to start off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336036/converting-to-websafe-colors-using-matlab/5339346#5339346) has the right approach, but you may be finding it daunting to get all those values off of the web page and into a map that you can use. You have a couple of options for creating the map...

One option is to actually get the source for the page using the function [URLREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/urlread.html) and parse out the numbers you need using the function [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) ("Did he just suggest [parsing HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)?!" Yes, I did. What can I say? I'm a loner, Dottie. A rebel.):

```
mapURL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Web-safe_colors';
urlText = urlread(mapURL);
matchExpr = ['<td style="background: #\w{3};">' ...
             '(?:<u>\*)?(\w{3})(?:\*</u>)?</td>'];
colorID = regexp(urlText,matchExpr,'tokens');
colorID = char([colorID{:}]);
[~,webSafeMap] = ismember(colorID,'0369CF');
webSafeMap = (webSafeMap-1)./5;
```

However, after I did the above I realized that there is a nice regular structure to the resulting web-safe color map values. This means you could actually ignore all the above mess and generate the map yourself using the functions [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) and [KRON](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/kron.html):

```
colorValues = (0:0.2:1).';  %'
webSafeMap = [repmat(colorValues,36,1) ...
              kron(colorValues,ones(36,1)) ...
              repmat(kron(colorValues,ones(6,1)),6,1)];
```

And then you can easily recolor, say, an RGB image using the functions [RGB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rgb2ind.html) and [IND2RGB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ind2rgb.html). For example:

```
imageRGB = imread('peppers.png');  %# Load a built-in image
imageRGB = ind2rgb(rgb2ind(imageRGB,webSafeMap),webSafeMap);
imshow(imageRGB);
```

[image: A web-safe version of peppers.png]

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `X = rgb2ind(RGB,MAP)` syntax: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rgb2ind.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Web-safe_colors appears to define the required MAP.